# Views displaying only one record on pagination

Tags: views, paging

Created a view which displays all user on the website, I have added pagination which displays 10 records on the page.

I am not sure but its displaying only one records but correct pagination link.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you've set the right "items per page" number in your view? Did you save well? Did you override the display after that without paying attention?

Comment: Nothing as such, i deleted the view and created again but still the issue is same.

Comment: Did you try with another content-type? (not user)

Comment: Another content type is working fine

Comment: Did you try with users but without operations widget?

Comment: Check your page source. Perhaps all ten records are present but nine are empty. I've had it before where I had issues with images not uploaded correctly.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue, setting "items per page" did not work. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your view and Click on Pager settings. and change the items per page

[image]

Comment: I checked the setting its same as you mentioned. But issues exist.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the Filter Criteria of your view meet the requirements/conditions.
For example, check if you are listing only the blocked users.